# Find m's condition that after a limited steps, every light bulb are turned on.

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:** On the roof of the theatre, it is designed as a square $n\times n$. each unit square has a light bulb. Each light bulb can be turned off or turned on.
Initial, every bulbs are turned off. Define $m\in N$ and $m\leq n$. Each step choose a column or  row then take m consecutive bulb and change their status. find m's condition that after a limited steps, every light bulb are turned on.

**May be this can help:** 
 define $(u_{n})$ that: $\left\{\begin{matrix}u_{1}=m\\ u_{n}=nm-2.\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\end{matrix}\right.$

Which $u_{i}$ is number of bright bulbs  $a_{i}$ is the number of light bulb change to dark after i steps. ($a_{1}=0$)

To satisfy problem's condition then: $u_{i}=n^{2} \Leftrightarrow  i.m-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=n^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If n is divisible by m, i=n^2 / m, with a trivial "filling" strategy.

Otherwise, it is not so clear which is the correct strategy to "fill", or even if it exists. The idea is that you should "touch" all the cells an odd number of times, and I remember there was a computer game with a similar concept, but with a "cross" filling pattern.

Actually, if n is odd and m is even, there should be no solution, due to parity.

Every cells needs an odd number of "impulses" to be switched on. The total number of cells is nxn, which is also odd. 
The total of needed impulses is the sum of an odd quantity of odd integers, which is also odd. By giving m (even) impulses each time, we can never get an odd total of impulses.

[image: Example of trivial filling strategy for n=4 and m mod n = 0]